# Redhat 7.7 dbus-org flooding messages log

Tags: rhel, d-bus

After installing Redhat 7.7 and by checking the /var/log/messages, I found the following messages are coming every minute:

```
Aug 24 19:33:00  dbus[1454]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Aug 24 19:33:00  systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
Aug 24 19:33:00  dbus[1454]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Aug 24 19:33:00  systemd: Started Hostname Service.
Aug 24 19:33:00  dbus[1454]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service'
Aug 24 19:33:00  systemd: Starting Time & Date Service...
Aug 24 19:33:00  dbus[1454]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Aug 24 19:33:00  systemd: Started Time & Date Service.
```

The question is: is there any way to stop this messages flood? We are using only the NetworkManager component.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.